# Setting RedirectStatusCode for AddHttpsRedirection is not having any effect

Tags: asp.net-core

Why is the following line not having any effect? It still gives me a 307!

```
services.AddHttpsRedirection(options => options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently);
```

Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace blog
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            services.AddHttpsRedirection(options => options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently);

            services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.LowercaseUrls = true;
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.Use((context, next) =>
                {
                    context.Request.PathBase = new PathString("/blog");
                    return next();
                });
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: fail to reproduce your issue. Try to clear the browser cache. If you create a new empty asp.net croe 2.1 project, and configure `services.AddHttpsRedirection(options => options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently);`, will this issue happen again?

Comment: yes, did just that and it's not redirecting. I think it's because of AKS where I have a service of type LoadBalancer. I'm not really sure how HTTPS works in that scenario. Locally it works fine.

Comment: What is AKS? Is it `Azure Kubernetes Service`? To check whether it is related with `LoadBalancer`, try to disable it. I am wondering you configured https required in `LoadBalancer`. I assume the redirection is implemented in ASK instead of `UseHttpsRedirection`

Answer (score 0):

As I read your startup config, I see that while not in development mode, you are also using HSTS. If you are testing with Chrome, analyze the network traffic response headers and see if it contains `Non-Authoritative-Reason: HSTS`. If this is the case, then HSTS is managing the redirect which is expected. The UseHttpsRedirection middleware is more of a fallback in this case for when the client does not support HSTS.

[image: Chrome dev tools network traffic showing HSTS redirect]

To test using a client that does not support HSTS and ensure the 301 is actually being returned during HTTPS redirection, use an API client such as Postman or Insomnia and view the timeline of the request.

[image: use insomnia to test https redirect without hsts]